# Emacs+AUCTeX: Improve ConTeXt mode indentation

Tags: context, emacs, auctex

I’m using Emacs with AUCTeX in `ConTeXt-mode` to compose my ConTeXt documents.  However, indentation is a little bit inconvenient for me.

Consider the following snippet:

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [before={\blank[big]},
   after={\blank[medium]}]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [
    before={\blank[big]},
    after={\blank[medium]},
  ]
```

If I execute `indent-region` onto this, it should *not* change (it is indented correctly, i.e. it follows the indentation scheme of the [ConTeXt source](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?q=setuphead) and the indentation scheme by our local ConTeXt expert [Aditya](https://github.com/adityam/context-slides-example/search?q=definehead)).  However, Emacs mangles this code to

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [before={\blank[big]},
    after={\blank[medium]}]

  \setuphead
    [subsection]
    [
      before={\blank[big]},
      after={\blank[medium]},
    ]
```

Especially the second `\setuphead` should not be indented further at this point.

Can anyone provide some Lisp magic to put in my `.emacs` to make indentation less painful?

Comment: I'll have a look at this (no guarantee I'll fin a solution, though).

Comment: @giordano Thank you very much for your effort!  I would also accept an answer explaining why it is not possible.

Comment: The easy answer is that currently there are no active AUCTeX developers that use ConTeXt ;-)  I just noticed that if `[section]` is in the same line as `\setuphead`, then indentation works correctly.  I.e., `\setuphead[section][` and then you break the line here.  I followed the example code at: http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/setuphead.  Maybe this is intended to work this way?

Comment: @giordano I’m following the ConTeXt source here: https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/search?q=setuphead

Comment: @LeonMeier I am not an Emacs user, the question is perfectly clear to me and, it seems, reproducable for other users.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Note: this question led to the [inclusion](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=d2dfab67e5fb37a6dfff1dd40cc82dc63013a2a8) of the following fix in AUCTeX.  It'll be available in the ELPA version 11.90.3 and the stable version 11.91.*

Warning: this answer does *almost* what you asked.

Add the following function definition to your init file:

```lisp
(with-eval-after-load "context"
  (defun ConTeXt-find-indent (&optional virtual)
    "Find the proper indentation of text after point.
VIRTUAL if non-nil indicates that we're only trying to find the
indentation in order to determine the indentation of something
else.  There might be text before point."
    (save-excursion
      (skip-chars-forward " \t")
      (or
       ;; Trust the current indentation, if such info is applicable.
       (and virtual (>= (current-indentation) (current-column))
        (current-indentation))
       ;; Put leading close-paren where the matching open brace would be.
       (condition-case nil
       (and (eq (char-syntax (char-after)) ?\))
        (save-excursion
          (skip-syntax-forward " )")
          (backward-sexp 1)
          (ConTeXt-find-indent 'virtual)))
     (error nil))
       ;; Default (maybe an argument)
       (let ((pos (point))
         (char (char-after))
         (indent 0)
         up-list-pos)
     ;; Look for macros to be outdented
     (cond ((looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                    (ConTeXt-environment-stop-name)))
        (setq indent (- indent ConTeXt-indent-basic)))
           ((looking-at ConTeXt-indent-item-re)
        (setq indent (- indent ConTeXt-indent-item))))
     ;; Find the previous point which determines our current indentation.
     (condition-case err
         (progn
           (backward-sexp 1)
           (while (or (> (current-column) (current-indentation))
              ;; Continue going back if we are
              ;; at a hanging optional group.
              (looking-at (regexp-quote ConTeXt-optop)))
         (backward-sexp 1)))
       (scan-error
        (setq up-list-pos (nth 2 err))))
     (cond
      ((= (point-min) pos) 0)  ; We're really just indenting the first line.
      ((integerp up-list-pos)
       ;; Have to indent relative to the open-paren.
       (goto-char up-list-pos)
       (if (and (not ConTeXt-indent-allhanging)
            (> pos (progn (down-list 1)
                  (forward-comment (point-max))
                  (point))))
           ;; Align with the first element after the open-paren.
           (current-column)
         ;; We're the first element after a hanging brace.
         (goto-char up-list-pos)
         (+ indent ConTeXt-indent-basic (ConTeXt-find-indent 'virtual))))
      ;; We're now at the "beginning" of a line.
      ((not (and (not virtual) (eq (char-after) ?\\)))
       ;; Nothing particular here: just keep the same indentation.
       (+ indent (current-column)))
      ;; We're now looking at an item.
      ((looking-at ConTeXt-indent-item-re)
       ;; Indenting relative to an item, have to re-add the outdenting.
       (+ indent (current-column) ConTeXt-indent-item))
      ;; We're looking at an environment starter.
      ((and (looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                    (ConTeXt-environment-start-name)))
        (not (looking-at (concat (regexp-quote TeX-esc)
                     (ConTeXt-environment-start-name)
                     ConTeXt-text)))) ; other environments?
       (+ indent (current-column) ConTeXt-indent-basic))
      (t
       (let ((col (current-column)))
         (if (not (and char (eq (char-syntax char) ?\()))
         ;; If the first char was not an open-paren, there's
         ;; a risk that this is really not an argument to the
         ;; macro at all.
         (+ indent col)
           (forward-sexp 1)
           (if (< (line-end-position)
              (save-excursion (forward-comment (point-max))
                      (point)))
           ;; we're indenting the first argument.
           (min (current-column) (+ ConTeXt-indent-arg col))
         (skip-syntax-forward " ")
         (current-column)))))))))))
```

This is a fixed version of the indenting function provided by AUCTeX.  There is only a minor change (the `(looking-at (regexp-quote ConTeXt-optop))` line) to adjust indentation after `[...]`.

Now your original code is indented as

```
\setuphead
  [section]
  [before={\blank[big]},
    after={\blank[medium]}]

\setuphead
  [subsection]
  [
    before={\blank[big]},
    after={\blank[medium]},
  ]
```

The only thing that I couldn't fix was indentation of `after={\blank[medium]}]` line, but for multiline settings inside `[...]` I'd suggest you to do like you did in the second case.

Please, tell me if you find this solution useful in the long run, so that I can install this change upstream.

Comment: I appended it to `ConTeXt-mode-hook` using `(add-hook 'ConTeXt-mode-hook (lambda () (...)))` but nothing happens.  If I just put the snippet in my `.emacs` as is I get `Symbol's function definition is void: with-eval-after-load`.

Comment: Which version of emacs are you using?

Comment: GNU Emacs 24.3.1, but I saw that `with-eval-after-load` was only introduced in 24.4.  I guess it’s time to update :)

Comment: What version of AUCTeX are you running? That shouldn't matter, though, as there hasn't been much work on ConTeXt mode lately.

Comment: the above threw a `If the problem persists, set x-select enable-clipboard-manager' to nil` not responding emacs on my system

Comment: @giordano I've been using this code for the last few months and so far your patch works fine for me.  I think it can go into the main AucTeX.  I also marked the answer as accepted.

Comment: @HenriMenke Great!  Thanks for testing, I [pushed the fix](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=auctex.git;a=commitdiff;h=d2dfab67e5fb37a6dfff1dd40cc82dc63013a2a8) to AUCTeX, so starting from the ELPA version 11.90.3 you'll have it by default. Keep suggesting improvements ;-)